# Programmatic SEO with WordPress

Tags: seo

I have a WordPress website with many filter parameters. I would like to do following :

- Every time someone goes to custom url it should extract queries from custom url, and show them filtered products based on query from the url, and I would modify content to be SEO friendly and essentially create hundreds of pages targeting long tail keywords. Something like nomad list did with their website : "https://marketingexamples.com/seo/long-tail-keywords"

For example, if someone goes to : "example.com/best-samsung-phones-in-europe" I want to extract "samsung" and "europe" as keywords that I'd plug in to filters and then show content based on those keywords.

I have been partially successful in this by making custom rewrite rules in functions.php, but only if someone goes to this type or url : "example.com/?category=samsung". What I'd like to do is make it more complex (adding more than one variable to query) as mentioned earlier, remove question marks and put hyphens between words.

Is anyone able to point me in the right direction ? Maybe writing rewrite rules in .htaccess file ?

Thanks in advance !